# Insert table from excel to outlook by keeping format and adding text after the table

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word, office-automation

I found some VBA code that seems to work exactly the way I want.
However, I don't know how I can add some additional text after the table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fktb6.png)

---

```
Sub esendtable()
Dim outlook As Object
Dim newEmail As Object
Dim xInspect As Object
Dim pageEditor As Object

Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set newEmail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

With newEmail
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Data"
    .Body = "Please find the requested information" & vbCrLf & "Best Regards"
    .Display
    
    Set xInspect = newEmail.GetInspector
    Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor
    
    Sheet5.Range("AA2:AB9").Copy
    
    
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteSpecial (wdFormatPlainText)
    .Display
    '.Send
    
    
         
    Set pageEditor = Nothing
    Set xInspect = Nothing

End With

Set newEmail = Nothing
Set outlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have no experience with VBA and tried to add ".Body = "further text" below the line
"pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteSpecial (wdFormatPlainText)"

but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The `Body` property doesn't contain any markup, so you can lost any formatting in the message body when dealing with the `Body` property. Instead, you need to use the [HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) property which returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the `Body` property immediately. So, if you need to paste some content after all the data displayed in the message body I'd suggest looking for the  tag in the HTML markup and paste the content before the closing tag, so you will be sure it is added after all the content displayed in the message body.

Comment: How would I have to write the code then? :)
As I don't know how to write VBA code.

Comment: See [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office)